# angular $interval - accessing variables outside of the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a $interval function inside a function tied to my controller scope that looks like this:

```
$interval(function () {
  if($scope.tocadoColour = 'red') {
    $scope.tocadoColour = 'black';
  } else {
    $scope.tocadoColour = 'red';
  }
}, 300);
```

I was expecting the variable $scope.tocadoColour to alternate between 'red' and 'black' on every interval but from putting in a couple of console.logs I can see that it's only ever going into the first part of the if statement. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing an assignment, not a comparison:

```
$scope.tocadoColour = 'red'
```

should be

```
$scope.tocadoColour === 'red'
```